# Can document certification statement be written its original language?

Tags: graduate-admissions, certification

I am from Indonesia and I am planning to apply for a master's program in Germany. I have had all of the important documents translated to English. However, there is one university that requires me to send documents by mail hence I need to issue a certified copy of the original documents. I have had my documents certified, however, the certification statement "This document is exactly the same as the original" is written in Indonesian language. Do I need to have this certification statement translated as well?

Comment: Ask the master's program.

Comment: Likely no help for you, but maybe useful to others: in almost all cases it is possible to replace the need for (expensive) certified copies in Germany by showing (in person) the original. The administrator will then make a copy (or take your "plain" copy and compare it with the original) and stamp and sign that the original was presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you do not say whether they require certified copies. The university has been through this a few times, so we can assume that they have adjusted their procedures. They must have access to someone who can evaluate credentials from your country, unless they just want the copies in order to be in a better position if they suspect fraud and just ask them from all applicants. If they have access to someone who evaluates credentials from Indonesia from you, they will be experienced enough to evaluate the certification.

You will find it hard for someone to certify the copies in English or German, as there is usually a set of rules. The fact that you asked means that you cannot provide them easily, which makes me guess that you cannot easily provide them with a certification in a main European language.

Conclusion: If they ask for documents in your local language, they will be able to handle a certification in your language.

As always: maybe you can ask the university.